# How can I emit an action and a stream in the same epic in redux-observable?

Tags: rxjs, redux-observable

I'm trying to upgrade my `executeWithRetries` utility (see below) to the most recent version of `redux-observable` where dispatching within an epic is no longer allowed.

Currently, this utility sees whether a required token is expired, and if so, it dispatches a `REFRESH_TOKEN` action and returns a new `action$` which responds to the resulting `REFRESH_TOKEN_SUCCESS` action by performing the original request, with the new token included. This works correctly.

Without dispatching the action explicitly, how can I both:

1. trigger the `REFRESH_TOKEN` action and also
2. create a stream that responds to another (resulting) action?

```js
import {isEmpty} from 'ramda';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
import {
  actions as guestActions,
  selectApiKey,
  selectGuestRefreshToken,
  selectGuestTokenExpiryMs,
  types as guestTypes,
} from '../reducers/guest';

const retryOrFail = ({ requestFactory, failure, success, store }) => {
  const state = store.getState();
  const apiKey = selectApiKey(state);
  const tokens = { apiKey, accessToken };
  return requestFactory.retry(tokens)
    .map(res => {
      return success(res);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      return retryOrFail({ requestFactory, failure, success, store });
    });
};

const refreshTokensIfNecessary = (store) => {
  const state = store.getState();
  const guestRefreshToken = selectGuestRefreshToken(state);
  const guestTokenExpiryMs = selectGuestTokenExpiryMs(state);
  const { dispatch } = store;

  const guestTokenExpired = () => guestRefreshToken && guestTokenExpiryMs && guestTokenExpiryMs < Date.now();

  if (guestTokenExpired()) {
    dispatch(guestActions.refreshToken(guestRefreshToken));
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

export default function executeWithRetries({ requestFactory, success, failure, store, action$ }) {
  const retryAction = action$.ofType(
    guestTypes.REFRESH_TOKEN_SUCCESS
  )
    .take(1)
    .switchMap(() => retryOrFail({ requestFactory, failure, success, store }));

  if (refreshTokensIfNecessary(store)) {
    return retryAction;
  }

  return requestFactoryToUse.execute()
    .map(res => success(res))
    .catch((err) => {
      return of(failure(err.toString()));
    });
}
```

It may be that this code is structured in a way that is no longer compatible with `redux-observable@latest`, since it is relying on dispatching an action, but I don't know of an alternative way to handle this case.

Comment: It's very unclear what you want to do. You have one action that you want to process and emit two different actions?

Comment: @martin I know how to emit multiple actions -- what I need to do here is:
1. emit an action -- `REFRESH_TOKEN` -- and then 
2. add an `action$` (effectively a temporary epic) to respond to an action that results from (1) -- `REFRESH_TOKEN_SUCCESS`. In the code above, I am simply dispatching the initial action then returning (2).

Comment: I'm curious, why do you need to call `dispatch`? With `redux-observable` you're generally meant to use `action$` - an observable of all Redux actions -  to create an observable of new actions. That's always been the idea behind the library.

Comment: @backtick The dispatch triggers the refreshing mechanism, which is defined elsewhere already. There are actually three tokens that may need refreshing; I've just simplified the code example. Dispatching the needed action simplifies the logic in this utility and reuses the refreshing functionality -- the new stream has only to respond to a successful refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a very simple solution which doesn't need dispatch:

```js
const refreshTokensIfNecessary = () => {
  ...

  if (tokenExpired) {
    return { type: 'REFRESH_TOKEN' };
  }

  return false;
};


...

  const retryAction$ = action$
    .pipe(
      ofType(
        types.REFRESH_TOKEN_SUCCESS,
      ),
      take(1),
      switchMap(() => retryOrFail({
        requestFactory: requestFactoryToUse, failure, success, store,
      })),
    );

  const refreshAction = refreshTokensIfNecessary();

  if (refreshAction) {

    return concat(
      of(refreshAction),
      retryAction$,
    );

  }
```

All I needed here was a stream `concat`enating stream of the action object and the `retryAction$`.

Answer (score 2):

Calling the store's `dispatch` method directly from a `redux-observable` epic is typically not ideal, and actually defeats the purpose of the library, which is to abstract away direct dispatch of actions in favor of transforming a stream of actions into a stream of new actions.

Your goal is to dispatch the token refresh action as well as trigger a stream listening for some resulting action. The general solution resembles this:

```
action$.pipe(
  ofType('SOME_TYPE'),
  op.mergeMap(action => {
    const onSuccess$ = action$.pipe(
      ofType('TOKEN_REFRESH_SUCCESS'),
      // ...rest of refreshed token logic
    );
    return Rx.merge(Rx.of(refreshToken()), onSuccess$);
  })
);
```

This will result in the dispatch of the token refresh action, as well as the initiation of a stream that listens for the token refresh success and emits any further actions.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you. I figured there was a simple solution like this, but I couldn't get it to work. I'll be removing the explicit dispatch logic and using this instead.

Comment: Actually, this setup is creating an infinite loop of attempted refreshes - do you know why that might be?

Comment: I had to add `take(1)` after the `mergeMap` to prevent an infinite loop. I don't suppose that's intended behavior, but I'm not sure how else to avoid it.

Comment: Unfortunately, the `onSuccess$` never seems to get triggered, either. It only appears to work upon a second request because it doesn't have to go through the refresh flow that time. @backtick

Answer (score 0):

EDIT -- This solution is not optimal - see my other answer instead.

---

It turns out I can still use `dispatch` directly if I:

1. Export the *instantiated* `store`, and
2. Importing the store into my epic utility directly and using `store.dispatch`.

*configureStore.js*

```js
...

export const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(epicMiddleware)),
);

const configureStore = () => {
  epicMiddleware.run(rootEpic);
  return store;
};

export default configureStore;
```

(Below sample epic would be better served with `mapTo` or (even better) within a reducer, but this demonstrates the capability anyway):

*cancelOrder.js*

```js
import { store } from '../configureStore';

export const CancelOrder = (action$, store, { dispatch }) => action$
  .pipe(
    ofType(types.CANCEL_ORDER),
    tap(() => store.dispatch(cancelSideEffectRequestAction)),
    ignoreElements()
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to add `store.dispatch` to the epic middleware's dependencies.

We need to extend redux-observable's epicMiddleware to include the store:

*epicMiddleware.js*

```js
import { createEpicMiddleware } from 'redux-observable'

const epicMiddleware = (store) => {
    const originalEpicMiddleware = createEpicMiddleware({
        dependencies: {
            dispatch: store.dispatch,
        },
    })

    const storeMiddleware = originalEpicMiddleware(store)

    epicMiddleware.run = originalEpicMiddleware.run

    return storeMiddleware
}

export default epicMiddleware
```

Then, we include our version of epicMiddleware in the store instantiation:

*store.js*

```js
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';

import epicMiddleware from './epicMiddleware';
import rootEpic from './rootEpic';
import rootReducer from './rootReducer';

const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    [],
    applyMiddleware(epicMiddleware),
);

epicMiddleware.run(rootEpic);

export default store;
```

And, finally, we can include `dispatch` from the `dependencies` in an epic like so:

*triggerEpic.js*

```js
import { ignoreElements, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { ofType } from 'redux-observable';

const triggerEpic = (action$, state$, { dispatch }) =>
    action$.pipe(
        ofType('TRIGGER_EPIC'),
        tap(() => {
            dispatch({ type: 'EPIC_TRIGGERED ' })
        }),
        ignoreElements(),
    );

export default triggerEpic;
```

See a working CodeSandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-observable-middleware-with-dispatch-0s09v

h/t @Sawtaytoes